# How to add holidays to DimTime table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I require to add the a holiday indicator in my DimTime table. I have already added a HolidayInd column which I need to update with the specific information. I also have a Holidays table which includes the holidays.

My current DimTime table (10 row sample). Full table goes from 1900 to 2050.

```
idDimTime FullTime      HolidayInd
20000101  2000-01-01    NULL
20000102  2000-01-02    NULL
20000103  2000-01-03    NULL
20000104  2000-01-04    NULL
20000105  2000-01-05    NULL
20000106  2000-01-06    NULL
20000107  2000-01-07    NULL
20000108  2000-01-08    NULL
20000109  2000-01-09    NULL
200001010 2000-01-10    NULL
```

My Holidays table (5row sample). I contains all the holidays between years 2000 and 2050

```
id idDimTime
1  20000101
2  20000110
3  20000320
4  20000420
5  20000421
```

My DimTime desired table

```
idDimTime FullTime    HolidayInd
20000101  2000-01-01    1
20000102  2000-01-02    0
20000103  2000-01-03    0
20000104  2000-01-04    0
20000105  2000-01-05    0
20000106  2000-01-06    0
20000107  2000-01-07    0
20000108  2000-01-08    0
20000109  2000-01-09    0
200001010 2000-01-10    1
```

I have joined both tables but unsure on how to update DimTime based on it

```
SELECT  
DT.IdDimTime
,CASE WHEN H.IdDimTime IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END AS HolidayInd
FROM DimTime DT

LEFT JOIN Holidays H
ON H.IdDimTime = DT.IdDimTime
WHERE DT.IdDimTime BETWEEN 20000101 AND 20501231
ORDER BY DT.IdDimTime
```

Comment: MERGE statement?

Comment: Update ... FROM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fairly straightforward and I'll show you how to do it in two steps.

1. Add the column to the table
2. Update only the holidays

---

For adding the column to the table, I'm going to add a non-nullable column with a default constraint. Whether you want to keep the constraint around after adding the column or not is up to you, but is a quick way to fill the entire column with one value (in this case, 0).

```sql
alter table DimTime
   add HolidayInd bit not null
      constraint DF_DimTime_HolidayInd default 0;
```

---

For updating just the holidays, I'll take the query you've already written and turn it into an update.

```sql
UPDATE DT
   SET HolidayInd = 1
FROM DimTime DT
JOIN Holidays H
ON H.IdDimTime = DT.IdDimTime
WHERE DT.IdDimTime BETWEEN 20000101 AND 20501231;
```

Note - I replaced the left join with an inner join. I'm able to do this as your original query needed rows for *all* dates whereas the query that drives the update only needs holidays.

Comment: You don't need a where clause the whole holiday table is getting matched against the dimension.  "My Holidays table (5row sample). I contains all the holidays between years 2000 and 2050"

Comment: Shouldnt I need it since DimTime goes back from 1900 and my Holidays table only has from 2000 to 2050?

Comment: @AndresMora - if that's the data that's in your holidays table, you don't need a where clause at all. You can (and should!) always run updates as a select statement first to validate what data will be updated. That said, it also doesn't hurt anything to leave it there.